# Realizar un Count de tablas foráneas con Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una tabla con éstos registros:

```
LEY  CIUDAD_ID
Ley1   1
Ley2   2
Ley3   2
Ley4   1
Ley5   3
Ley6   2
Ley7   3
```

Necesito que mediante Eloquent obtenga un contador por ciudad. Similar a esto:

```
CIUDAD_ID   CANTIDAD
1             2
2             3
3             2
```

¿Es posible conseguir eso?

Comment: Sí, es posible.

Comment: ¿Cómo @Shaz? ¿Me lo podrías decir?

Comment: Muéstranos un intento, así sea con SQL puro si es que no conoces Eloquent, y con gusto te ayudamos.